# Aggregating data in an array based on date

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to aggregate data based on timestamp. Basically I'd like to create an array for each day.

So lets say I've a query like so:

```
SELECT date(task_start) AS started, task_start 
  FROM tt_records
  GROUP BY started, task_start
  ORDER BY started DESC;
```

The output is:

```
+------------+------------------------+
| started    | task_start             |
|------------+------------------------|
| 2021-08-30 | 2021-08-30 16:45:55+00 |
| 2021-08-29 | 2021-08-29 06:47:55+00 |
| 2021-08-29 | 2021-08-29 15:41:50+00 |
| 2021-08-28 | 2021-08-28 12:59:20+00 |
| 2021-08-28 | 2021-08-28 14:50:55+00 |
| 2021-08-26 | 2021-08-26 20:46:44+00 |
| 2021-08-24 | 2021-08-24 16:28:05+00 |
| 2021-08-23 | 2021-08-23 16:22:41+00 |
| 2021-08-22 | 2021-08-22 14:01:10+00 |
| 2021-08-21 | 2021-08-21 19:45:18+00 |
| 2021-08-11 | 2021-08-11 16:08:58+00 |
| 2021-07-28 | 2021-07-28 17:39:14+00 |
| 2021-07-19 | 2021-07-19 17:26:24+00 |
| 2021-07-18 | 2021-07-18 15:04:47+00 |
| 2021-06-24 | 2021-06-24 19:53:33+00 |
| 2021-06-22 | 2021-06-22 19:04:24+00 |
+------------+------------------------+
```

As you can see the `started` column has repeating dates.

What I'd like to have is:

```
+------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| started    | task_start                                       |
|------------+--------------------------------------------------|
| 2021-08-30 | [2021-08-30 16:45:55+00]                         |
| 2021-08-29 | [2021-08-29 06:47:55+00, 2021-08-29 15:41:50+00] |
| 2021-08-28 | [2021-08-28 12:59:20+00, 2021-08-28 14:50:55+00] |
| 2021-08-26 | [2021-08-26 20:46:44+00]                         |
| 2021-08-24 | [2021-08-24 16:28:05+00]                         |
| 2021-08-23 | [2021-08-23 16:22:41+00]                         |
| 2021-08-22 | [2021-08-22 14:01:10+00]                         |
| 2021-08-21 | [2021-08-21 19:45:18+00]                         |
| 2021-08-11 | [2021-08-11 16:08:58+00]                         |
| 2021-07-28 | [2021-07-28 17:39:14+00]                         |
| 2021-07-19 | [2021-07-19 17:26:24+00]                         |
| 2021-07-18 | [2021-07-18 15:04:47+00]                         |
| 2021-06-24 | [2021-06-24 19:53:33+00]                         |
| 2021-06-22 | [2021-06-22 19:04:24+00]                         |
+------------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

I need a query to achieve that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_agg()`

```
SELECT date(task_start) AS started, array_agg(task_start)
FROM tt_records
GROUP BY started
ORDER BY started DESC;
```

If you want a JSON array, rather than a native Postgres array, use `jsonb_agg()` instead